# How do I move the input boxes from two forms closer together?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="insideimagelogin">
<h4>Existing User Login</h4>
<form action="login" method="post">
<p>
   <label for="username"></label>
   <input name="username" type="text" value"" placeholder="Email" id="username"/>
</p>
<p>
   <label for="password"></label>
   <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="password"/>
</p>
</form>
```

That's my code above but the username and password box are too far apart. I want them within a few px of each other. I have tried changing the margin and padding on my .css file with no luck.

```
#insideimagelogin {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    margin: 0;
    left: 536px;
    }
```

I could probably create another div and then I can move them together, but I don't really want to do that. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: show us more CSS, especially for `p`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce or eliminate the margin on the paragraphs.

```
p {
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/D9LaY/)**

You can do the same for the input elements if you want them as close as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
form>p
{
margin-top:1px;   
margin-bottom:1px;   
}
```

This sets the top and bottom margin of any `p` that is a child of a `form` to 1px.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nr5d/1/) (make sure to scroll to the right to see the form)

Comment: `any p that is a child of a form`. I think you mean any `p` tag that is a descendant of a `form` tag

Comment: it usually selects children rather than any descendants

Comment: No, it will select **every** `p` that is a descendant of `form`. Child is denoted by the `>`

Comment: Thanks for the input! Appreciate your help!